# Getting initial layouts correct in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout, autolayout

I have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Amongst others, it has a `UIView` property I've called `boxView` (e.g. `@IBOutlet var boxView: UIView!`). I'm trying to apply a special border around to this boxView, a rectangle with only some of the corners rounded.

I elected to use `awakeFromNib()` as the point to do this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer() // for the outline
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor // black line
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 1.0 // of width 1
    borderLayer.fillColor = nil // no fill
    borderLayer.frame = self.boxView.bounds // align the layer with the boxView
    borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.boxView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .BottomRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath // set the path with a UIBezierPath rounding just the bottom right corner
    self.boxView.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, atIndex: 0) // insert it at the bottom so we can find it later
}
```

On my iPhone 6, it works fine. But on an iPad, it comes up wrong. It is not as wide as it should be. I have size classes enabled, but am just using any x any. The boxView is aligned to the margins of the container view.

With some debug prints, I see that on the iPad, at the `awakeFromNib()` runs, the width is 520. I'm not sure where this number comes from. Thinking that this is some intermediate size, I added the following method to my subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let borderLayer = self.box.layer.sublayers?.first as? CAShapeLayer {
        borderLayer.frame = self.boxView.bounds
        borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.boxView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .BottomRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath
    }
}
```

Basically, if the view change sizes, try to adjust the path accordingly. Using more debug statements, I can see that the view is indeed changing to be of width 688. I'm not sure what is triggering that. I am shuffling the order of the cells as they are populated. But not all of the views get resized, so I end up with most of them being fixed, but not all. If I scroll them off screen, and then back, they appear to get resized finally.

What is the right way to do layout adjustments with UITableViewCell's? Especially, initial layout adjustments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing like this needs to happen in `drawRect`. It's called when size is laid out correctly. I banged my head against a similar situation, and this was the best spot to put my drawing code that it would be called only once, and done correctly.

So, you'd do:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    //draw stuff here
}
```

Comment: No, I'm saying you should put that code inside `drawRect`, as you'll have proper bounds available then.

Comment: Yikes. I tried using an override of drawRect() on the custom UITableViewCell to adjust the layer shape. Which actually worked. This seems excessively wrong for some reason. Adjusting layers inside of a draw method seems like it violates something, but you're correct, it does work.

Comment: I mean you could use a different type of drawing if it made you feel better... but if it works?

Comment: Yes, I could just fetch the current context, and stroke the same path, rather than manipulating the layer. Which might be easier. Which both answers my question and doesn't. It seems to imply that any sort of layer based manipulation for UITableViewCells is going to be problematic. But the whole reason for using layers, is to avoid implementing a drawRect() method on a custom view.